# Can't catch 404 error in Composite C1

Tags: http-status-code-404, c1-cms

I've set up a multi language webapplication using Composite hostnames like it's mentioned  here: http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/UrlConfiguration/Hostnames.

Now I would like to log which URL the user could not find. I am struggling to figure out how to do this. I've tried custom razor functions on my 404 page defined in Composite, but Request.UrlReferer is always null. The FileNotFoundHandler.ashx handler inside Renderers, never seems to be hit.

Any idéas?

Cheers 
Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Request.RawUrl in the razor function.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.